# rails ajax:complete doesn't fire on a dynamically created form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, jquery-events

I'm fetching a form via ajax from the server, the form's id is "signin", after I fetch the form I'm showing it as bootstrap modal dialog.

the form shows successfully, Now the form has remote set to true and when I submit the form with empty fields I get 401 unauthorized in chromium's console as expected.

In application.js I have attached event ajax:error like this:

```
$(document).on('ajax:error','#signin',function(event,xhr,status,error)
{
   $('#signin .modal-body').prepend(xhr.responseText); \\ line 1
});
```

Problem is the event doesn't fire, I have verified this by using chromium's debugger(it doesn't even reach line 1).

The event gets added successfully but it doesn't fire.

Why is this happening ?

I'm using rails 4.2.5 here just so you know.

Comment: Have you tried that bind event on `#signin` directly? `$("#signin").on(...)`

Comment: @JaehyunShin because the form is dynamically created it won't work, do you want me to try it after the form is added ?

Comment: No, just I can not find anything wrong in your code.

Comment: @JaehyunShin I'm using ajaxify_rails gem and assigning class "no_ajaxify"  to my form, does that have a relation to my problem ?

Comment: I've never use ajaxify_rails. sorry, but ajaxify_rails can make conflict. It's old and no update. Why don't you use Turbolinks

Comment: @JaehyunShin is there a way to set main container for turbolinks ? that is set what will be replaced by any ajax request that doesn't have action.js.erb nor it has respond_to format.js ? or should I pass "change" to every render I have in my project ?

Comment: Just add turbolinks gem in Gemfile and put that in your application.js file, Read rails document.

Comment: Is '#signin' a button? Is it sending request with remote: true? Maybe not, as you have '#singnin .modal-body'

Comment: @Alexei.B '#signin' is a form, '.modal-body' is a div inside my form

Comment: First, make sure 'ajax:error' is activated on document. $(document).on('ajax:error',function() {alert("activated")})

Comment: @Alexei.B is there a way to know which link caused the ajax request ? I have other links that trigger ajax request and I want to do other things with them

Comment: Can you publish the form? And fragment of javascript, if any?